Slicing using polars .filter is slower than pandas .loc
I am trying to switch some of my pandas code to polars to leverage it's performance. I have found that the .filter operation is much slower than a similar slicing using .loc.
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

date_index = pd.date_range(dt.date(2001,1,1), dt.date(2020,1,1),freq='1H')
n = date_index.shape[0]
test_pd = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(1,100, n), index=date_index, columns = ['test'])
test_pl = pl.DataFrame(test_pd.reset_index())
test_dates = date_index[np.random.randint(0,n,1000)]

st = time.perf_counter()
for i in test_dates:
    d = test_pd.loc[i,:]
print(f"Pandas {time.perf_counter() - st}")


st = time.perf_counter()
for i in test_dates:
    d = test_pl.filter(index=i)
print(f"Polars {time.perf_counter() - st}")

Pandas 0.1854726000019582
Polars 2.1125728000042727

Is there some other way to speedup the slicing operation in polars?

Polars doesn't use indexes, so random access of one specific element (if not by row number) will always have to loop over all the data. But you can efficiently get all the dates you are interested in in one go using a left join:
test_dates_df = pl.DataFrame({"index": test_dates})
out = test_dates_df.join(test_pl, on="index", how="left")

Then out[0] contains the row where the index column matches test_dates[0], etc.
On my machine this gives the following times:
Pandas 0.029560166876763105
Polars 0.0009763331618160009


Thanks for the prompt response. In the application where I want to use Polars, the date generation, happens one at a time. When the date generation happens, it fetches the data, processes it, and fetches the next date.

@parmatma Polars is probably not the right tool for the job then, if you're looking to do repeated queries with a single point of data. At least not for that portion of the process.

You could maintain a map of dates to row numbers and then use df.row(map[date])
